# .NET Core mono-repo ideal referencing strategy

Tags: c#, .net-core, monorepo

Let's say we have `Controller.cs`, `Engine.cs` and `DbRepo.cs` files:

- `Controller.cs` is in an ASP.NET `proj1.csproj`
- `Engine.cs` and `DbRepo.cs` are in a class library `proj2`

I'm thinking of separating engines and repos into different projects.

Is there an advantage in holding `Engine.cs` and `DbRepo.cs` in different projects (proj2 and proj3 respectively) so in this way proj1 will have a reference to proj2 which will be thinner and proj2 will reference proj3?

Important note: currently it's not expected that there will be an application that will use `DbRepo.cs` without `Engine.cs`.

Does direct reference (proj1 -> proj2) have any difference from indirect reference (proj1 -> proj3 through proj2) in a manner of build time or memory or any other aspect?